# Is the matrix $R$ in the $QR$ decomposition unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to know for positive diagonal elements why is $R$  in $QR$ decomposition unique.

My guess is it must have something to do with linearly independence of the column of $R$, but then I can think of a property that lead me to uniqueness of $R$.

Comment: $QR=Q'R'$ iff $Q'^{-1}QR=R'$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Whoa, easy peasy! But what's the role of positive diagonal elements in your proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [see this page.](http://www.math4all.in/public_html/linear%20algebra/proof8.5.11.html) (it uses positivity in the middle, in case you wonder).

Comment: Sorry, but the link is down. Can you share the response or another link?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/989638/167153).

Comment: One part of proof on link I think is wrong? They write $\frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i} = \frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i}$. But, do they mean to say $\frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i} = \frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}$?

Comment: I agree, that part is definitely wrong.